# Neo4j gem - Updating relationship properties method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, update-attributes, neo4j.rb

This is a fairly simple question.

Is there a specific method for updating properties for relationships in the gem? I can't seem to do a simple `update_attributes` or `update`.

My relationship is created and update is undefined for nil class.

```
event = Event.find(params[:event]) 
invite = Invite.create_invitation(event, current_user, nil) #creates relationship
invite.update(interested: params[:interest])
```

Is there another method that I should be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you get an error about undefined for nil class, it should be an immediate signal to you that the problem is the variable on which you're calling the method, not the method you're calling. In other words, since it's saying that `nil` does not have an `update` method, your focus should be on the variable that is actually nil. The question here: why is `invite` returning `nil` instead of a relationship?

Since you're using a custom class method to create the relationship, I'm guessing that you're not telling it to return the right object. It should look something like this:

```
def self.create_invitation(event, user, something_else = nil)
  rel = InvitationRel.new(from_node: event, to_node: user)
  if rel.save
    rel
  else
    # return an error, maybe rel.errors.full_messages?
  end
end
```

Then your controller needs to check that the rel was actually created correctly.

```
event = Event.find(params[:event]) 
invite = Invite.create_invitation(event, current_user, nil) #creates relationship
if invite.neo_id.nil?
  # the rel did not create correctly, neo_id is only present on persisted objects
else
  invite.update(interested: params[:interest])
end
```

This feels to me like you're taking a long way around this problem. You don't need to separate the creation of the relationship and setting the `interested` property, you can just do it in one call to the DB:

```
event = Event.find(params[:event])
invite = InviteRel.new(from_node: event, to_node: current_user, interested: params[:interest])
if invite.save?
  # rel was created, move on
else
  # something wrong in the rel, figure out what it was
end
```

Since you know you're always going to create that `interested` property, this looks like a good place to add a validation to your model to ensure that the property is always set on create.

Comment: Thanks chris. Ruby typically returns the last object. If you simply had `InvitationRel.new(from_node: event, to_node: user).save` I am wondering why that relationship object is not returned. Why do we need to explicitly return it? Is there a subtly in the creation that I'm not aware of?

Comment: `save` doesn't return the object created on which it's called, it returns a boolean of whether the object was or was not saved successfully. `create` does return the object but gives no indication of whether it was successful. That's why you see the `if obj.save then do_this else do_that end` pattern everywhere.